# Equidistribution theorem of Weyl

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory

Have you examples of applications of Equidistribution theorem of Weyl in proofs of irrationality of numbers?

I don't know if "if and only if" is true for this theorem.

Comment: It is an "iff" statement since integer multiples of a rational $\frac{p}{q}$ are not uniformly distributed $\text{mod} \space 1$ (they all have denominator $\le q$).  So possibly there are some irrationality proofs like you seek but I don't know of any.

Comment: Perhaps OP is asking if equidistribution of a sequence $a\cdot n$ can be used to show that $a$ is irrational? I don't think Weyl works in that direction but at least it's a question. Vote to reopen.